# What is the difference between DispHTMLWindow2 and Window in JS/IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

In IE11, sometimes in the debugger I see that the type of a frame object is `DispHTMLWindow2`, while at other times it is `Window`. What is the difference between the two? I couldn't find any documentation on DispHTMLWindow2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the class name being used for the `IHTMLWindow2 interface`, which is an extension of `IHTMLWindow` (and there is a IHTMLWindow3/4/5/6 too)

Simply put, the extended versions give a Windows developer more features when doing webbrowser based development.

Here are a few links that might help shed some light

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa741505(v=vs.60)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa741505
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/497d9c38-02f5-4ac8-a928-a29213a7b90b/relationship-between-iwebbrowser2-ihtmlwindow-ihtmldocument?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: I noticed that IHTMLWindow2 doesn't have a postMessage method in the first link, why is that? At first I thought maybe they show only functions not available in Window, but they have stuff like `parent` listed.

Comment: @sashoalm It is a matter of implementation, higher versions have more features so in [`IHTMLWindow6 interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/cc288123(v=vs.71)) you'll find `postMessage`

Comment: @sashoalm And deeper info than the above I don't have at the moment (long time since I did Windows development :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful as it is :)